# sbt-avro is not generating Scala classes, possible settings issue

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, avro

I'm trying to use [sbt-avro](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-avro) in a Scala project to generate Scala classes from an Avro schema.

Here is the project structure:

```
multi-tenant/
    build.sbt
    project/
        plugins.sbt
    src/
        main/
            resources/
                avro/
                    Measurement.avsc
            scala/
                com.mycom.multitenant/
                    Producer
```

And here is the build.sbt (note that I try to point the sbt-avro plugin to the location of my Avro source files using the avroSource setting):

```
version := "1.0"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  settings(
    inThisBuild(List(
      organization := "com.mycom",
      scalaVersion := "2.12.15"
    )),
    name := "multi-tenant",
    avroSource := new File("src/main/resources/avro"),
  )

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.avro" % "avro" % "1.11.0"
```

the plugins.sbt:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.github.sbt" % "sbt-avro" % "3.4.0")

// Java sources compiled with one version of Avro might be incompatible with a
// different version of the Avro library. Therefore we specify the compiler
// version here explicitly.
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.avro" % "avro-compiler" % "1.11.0"
```

When building in IntelliJ (top-right green hammer button), no sources get generated. I have also tried writing `compile` in the sbt console with the same result.

Here are some logs which appear when I first start up the sbt console in IntelliJ. It may contain some clues:

```
[info] welcome to sbt 1.5.8 (Oracle Corporation Java 11.0.11)
[info] loading global plugins from /home/sahand/.sbt/1.0/plugins
[info] loading settings for project multi-tenant-build from plugins.sbt,idea.sbt ...
[info] loading project definition from /home/sahand/multi-tenant/project
[warn] Unrecognized repository Scala Plugin Bundled Repository, ignoring it
[info] loading settings for project root from build.sbt ...
[info] set current project to multi-tenant (in build file:/home/sahand/multi-tenant/)
[warn] there's a key that's not used by any other settings/tasks:
[warn]  
[warn] * root / avroSource
[warn]   +- /home/sahand/multi-tenant/build.sbt:10
[warn]  
[warn] note: a setting might still be used by a command; to exclude a key from this `lintUnused` check
[warn] either append it to `Global / excludeLintKeys` or call .withRank(KeyRanks.Invisible) on the key
[info] Defining Global / ideaPort
[info] The new value will be used by Compile / compile, Test / compile
[info] Reapplying settings...
[info] set current project to multi-tenant (in build file:/home/sahand/multi-tenant/)
```

Note the warning about the `avroSource` setting not being used. Maybe that is why it cannot generate the sources for me? It might simply not find the Avro source files. How can I fix the issue and get my generated Scala classes?

Answer (score 1):

[sbt-avro](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-avro) project is meant to generate Java classes. If you want Scala classes to be generated, I suggest looking at [sbt-avrohugger](https://github.com/julianpeeters/sbt-avrohugger).

In a project structure like yours using sbt-avrohugger, your build.sbt may look like

```
lazy val AvroGenSettings = Seq(
  Compile / sourceGenerators += (Compile / avroScalaGenerateSpecific).taskValue,
  avroSpecificSourceDirectories in Compile += (resourceDirectory in Compile).value / "avro",
  avroSpecificScalaSource in Compile := {
    val base = thisProject.value.base
    new File(new File(new File(new File(new File(base, "target"), "scala"), "src_managed"), "main"), "compiled_avro")
  },
  managedSourceDirectories in Compile ++= baseDirectory { base =>
    Seq(
      base / "target/scala/src_managed/main/compiled_avro"
    )
  }.value
)

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  settings(
    inThisBuild(List(
      organization := "com.mycom",
      scalaVersion := "2.12.15"
    )),
    name := "multi-tenant"
  ).settings(AvroGenSettings: _*)
```

To do that, remember to import the plugin.

```
addSbtPlugin("com.julianpeeters" % "sbt-avrohugger" % "2.0.0-RC24")
```